# Convert an infinite tree into an infinite stream

Tags: ocaml, lazy-sequences

**Description of the problem**

I have a lazy infinite binary tree:

```
type 'a tree_node = TN of 'a * 'a inf_btree * 'a inf_btree
  and 'a inf_btree = 'a tree_node Lazy.t 

let rec ibt_map (f : 'a -> 'b) (t : 'a inf_btree) : 'b inf_btree = 
  let TN (x, ltree, rtree) = Lazy.force t in 
  lazy (TN (f x, ibt_map f ltree, ibt_map f rtree))

let rec example : int inf_btree = 
  lazy (TN (1, 
              ibt_map ((+) 1) example, 
              ibt_map ((+) 2) example
           )
       ) 
;;
```

and a lazy stream:

```
type 'a link_node = LN of 'a * 'a stream 
  and 'a stream = 'a link_node Lazy.t
```

Now I want to transform a tree into a stream, in such a way that it preserves the order of the elements in the tree.  More precisely, I want elements close to the root to come early in the stream.  However, if it's done depth-first then half the tree will never occur in the stream:

```
let df_tree_to_stream (t : 'a inf_btree) : 'a stream = 
  let TN (x, ltree, rtree) = Lazy.force t in 
  let substream1 = df_tree_to_stream ltree in 
  let substream2 = df_tree_to_stream rtree in 
  lazy (LN (x, substream1)) 
  (* how to work in substream2 ??? *)
```

---

**An attempted solution by alternation**

We could try to merge the two streams so that they alternate, but then the order of the elements will not be preserved. In the given example, the tree looks like

```
       1
    3    2
   5 6  4 3
  .........
```

The order of the stream should be

```
1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, ...
```

But if we simply alternate the streams returned by subtrees, then the tree rooted at 3 would have streams that start with 5 and 6.  So this subtree transforms into the stream `3, 5, 6 ...`  The other subtree becomes `2, 4, 3 ...`  So the overall resulting stream would be

```
1, 3, 2, 5, 4, ...
```

We could instead manage the order of visitation of nodes in the tree by maintaining a queue.

---

**Question**

My question is, is there simpler a way? Can we get the desired order not using a queue and only using recursion?

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to try to get away from the tail recursive version, but yes you can hide the queue of the breadth first traversal in a call stack. For instance, you can define an interleave function that switches the left and right source with decreasing frequency:

```ml
let rec interleave first period count l r () =
  if count = 0 then
    if first then
      interleave false period period r l ()
    else
      let period = 2 * period in
      interleave true period period r l ()
  else
    match l () with
    | Seq.Nil -> r ()
    | Seq.Cons(y,l) ->
      Seq.Cons(y, interleave first period (count-1) l r)

let interleave = interleave true 1 1

let rec to_seq tree () =
  let lazy (TN(x,l,r)) = tree in
  Seq.Cons(x, interleave (to_seq l) (to_seq r))
```